Why my chrome Extension not working, although code seems correct
I am creating a website blocking extension where user, add website he wants to block with a password.
And when he tries to open that site, a html page comes in front of him asking for the password, and when user put in the password , he got the access of the site.
but this is not happening, after blocking a website when i tries to open it, that html page is not coming and website is not blocked , below is the whole code , please check and help
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Website Blocker",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "declarativeNetRequest",
    "storage",
    "activeTab"
    
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "block.jpg",
      "48": "block.jpg",
      "128": "block.jpg"
    }
  },
  "declarative_net_request": {
    "rule_resources": [{
      "id": "ruleset_1",
      "enabled": true,
      "path": "rules.json"
    }]
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "block.jpg",
    "48": "block.jpg",
    "128": "block.jpg"
  },
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "resources": [ "blocked.html" ],
      "matches": [ "<all_urls>" ]
    }
  ]
}

this above is  code of manifest.json
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
  console.log("Extension installed");
  chrome.storage.sync.set({ blockedSites: [] });
  updateBlockedSitesRules([]);
});

chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener((changes, namespace) => {
  if (changes.blockedSites) {
    updateBlockedSitesRules(changes.blockedSites.newValue);
  }
});

function updateBlockedSitesRules(blockedSites) {
  console.log("Updating rules with blocked sites: ", blockedSites);

  const removeRuleIds = Array.from({ length: 1000 }, (_, index) => index + 1); // Adjust the length as needed
  chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules({
    removeRuleIds: removeRuleIds,
    addRules: []
  }, () => {
    const rules = blockedSites.map((site, index) => ({
      id: index + 1,
      priority: 1,
      action: { type: "redirect", redirect: { extensionPath: `/blocked.html?targetUrl=${encodeURIComponent(`*://${site.url}/*`)}` } },
      condition: { urlFilter: `*://${site.url}/*`, resourceTypes: ["main_frame"] }
    }));

    chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules({
      removeRuleIds: [],
      addRules: rules
    }, () => {
      if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        console.error("Error updating rules: ", chrome.runtime.lastError);
      } else {
        console.log("Rules updated successfully");
        chrome.declarativeNetRequest.getDynamicRules((rules) => {
          console.log("Current dynamic rules: ", rules);
        });
      }
    });
  });
}

// Initial rules setup
chrome.storage.sync.get(['blockedSites'], (result) => {
  updateBlockedSitesRules(result.blockedSites || []);
}); 
 

this is background.js file code
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Blocked</title>
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      height: 100vh;
      background-color: #f8d7da;
    }
    .container {
      text-align: center;
      background: white;
      padding: 20px;
      border-radius: 10px;
      box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    }
    input {
      margin: 10px 0;
      padding: 10px;
      border: 1px solid #ced4da;
      border-radius: 5px;
      width: 100%;
    }
    button {
      padding: 10px 20px;
      background: #007bff;
      color: white;
      border: none;
      border-radius: 5px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>This website is protected</h1>
    <p>Enter password to access</p>
    <input type="password" id="passwordInput" placeholder="Enter Password">
    <button id="submitBtn">Enter</button>
  </div>
  <script>
    document.getElementById('submitBtn').addEventListener('click', () => {
      const password = document.getElementById('passwordInput').value.trim();
      const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
      const targetUrl = decodeURIComponent(urlParams.get('targetUrl'));

      chrome.storage.sync.get(['blockedSites'], (result) => {
        const site = result.blockedSites.find(site => `*://${site.url}/*` === targetUrl);
        if (site && site.password === password) {
          window.location.href = `https://${site.url}`;
        } else {
          alert('Incorrect password');
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>

this is blocked.html code
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Website Blocker</title>
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        margin: 10px;
      }
      input, button {
        margin: 5px 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Website Blocker</h1>
    <input type="text" id="urlInput" placeholder="Enter URL">
    <input type="password" id="passwordInput" placeholder="Enter Password">
    <button id="blockBtn">Block</button>
    <button id="showBtn">Show Blocked Sites</button>
    <ul id="blockedSitesList"></ul>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>

this is popup.html code
document.getElementById('blockBtn').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const urlInput = document.getElementById('urlInput').value.trim();
  const passwordInput = document.getElementById('passwordInput').value.trim();

  if (urlInput && passwordInput) {
    chrome.storage.sync.get(['blockedSites'], (result) => {
      const blockedSites = result.blockedSites || [];
      blockedSites.push({ url: urlInput, password: passwordInput });
      chrome.storage.sync.set({ blockedSites }, () => {
        console.log("Blocked sites updated: ", blockedSites);
      });
      document.getElementById('urlInput').value = '';
      document.getElementById('passwordInput').value = '';
      showBlockedSites(blockedSites);
    });
  }
});

document.getElementById('showBtn').addEventListener('click', () => {
  chrome.storage.sync.get(['blockedSites'], (result) => {
    showBlockedSites(result.blockedSites || []);
  });
});

function showBlockedSites(blockedSites) {
  const list = document.getElementById('blockedSitesList');
  list.innerHTML = '';
  blockedSites.forEach((site) => {
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.textContent = site.url;
    list.appendChild(li);
  });
}

this is popup.js code
// Example: Notify the user
console.log("This website is blocked.");

content.js

have you checked the browser developer tools console for any errors? have you confirmed that console.log("Current dynamic rules: ", rules); runs?

Sites should be listed in host_permissions in manifest.json to allow redirecting them.
You can allow all URLs as "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"], but a better solution that reduces the review time in the web store would be to use "optional_host_permissions" and ask the user to grant the access to the site in the popup, see the example in documentation.
